# Pass generic type from a parent to its children in React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typing

i would like to know if it's possible to pass a generic type from a parent component to its children like this:

```
interface ParentProps<T> extends PropsWithChildren {
    data: T;
}

const Parent = <T,>(props: ParentProps<T>) => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

interface ChildProps<T> {
    fieldName: keyof T;
}

const Child = <T,>({ fieldName }: ChildProps<T>) => {
    return <div>{fieldName}</div>;
};

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <Parent data={{ firstName: 'John' }}>
            <Child fieldName='firstName' />
            <Child fieldName='lastName' /> // would like to get an error here
        </Parent>
    );
};
```

And I don't want to manually cast the children like this:

```
type Data = {
   firstName: string;
}

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <Parent data={{ firstName: 'John' }}>
            <Child<Data> fieldName='firstName' />
            <Child<Data> fieldName='lastName' /> // error triggered bc the component is casted and the filedname doesn't exist
        </Parent>
    );
};
```